# SIP providers with local number portability?

Tags: voip, sip

Anyone know of a good voip provider that will allow me to port my existing phone number to their service *and* be cheap?  I'm looking to spend no more than $15 a month; am I in dreamland?

Also, I've read various things about LNP -- one indiciated that if I port my number from my cell phone (is that even possible?) to a VOIP provider I wouldn't be able to port it back to a normal voice provider.  Any experience with this?

As background -- my employer provides me a phone but I'm not anxious to give up the phone number everyone else knows to reach me at.  Yes, I can notify people, but I figure there will always be stragglers and they are the ones I especially want to keep in touch with....

---

I've migrated my service to this and it works, even over an AT&T 3g network connection.  The 3g connection is pretty poor quality, but good enough to answer the call (or check voice mail messages) and tell the person that I'll call them back.  I can then switch to a wifi connection and call back using SIP or use the AT&T cellular services and call them back directly.

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: What land are you in, geographically? USA I suppose, but assumptions are the mother of all ...

Comment: USA -- specifically Cambridge MA with a 781 area code phone # to port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Callcentric](http://www.callcentric.com/lnp/) has provided me with amazing service for over a year. (I'm also in Canada but they offer service to the US)

They offer LNP in most parts of US/CAN and they've answered every support ticket within a day.

I use their forwarding and "calling card" features for all sorts of things.

They're also a [BYOD](http://www.callcentric.com/features/bring_your_own_device) provider so any voip app or hardware will work.  In your case, I'd just move your old number to them and have it forward calls to your work cell.

Good luck

Comment: I'm going with callcentric.  It looks like they offer 80% of what I want -- the only limitation seems to be that outgoing calls can't be associated with a number that's been ported over with LNP.  Oh well, that's not really too useful to me as I'm unlikely to use this service for outgoing calls much.

Comment: Huh.. I didn't know there was an issue with call display on ported numbers.  Try their support people, if there's a way of making it work they'll find a way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Canada and I use Vbuzzer (.com).

With my plan I pay much less, but you may have different needs.

Comment: Thanks -- it doesn't look like they do LNP for the USA.  It looks like a pretty good service, though.